# How to update a screen when an event occurs at another screen?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, screen, dynamic

I am developing a chat application in blackberry.
I have made a main screen which acts like the home screen of the application. Whenever application is started this screen appears first.

There are like 5 screens (1 Main screen and 4 other screens). 
My problem is..I want to update this 1 main screen when something happens on other 4 screens. Like For example, if I'm using the voice recording screen of my application. I have to add an icon to my main screen of the application indicating I have recorded a voice message after I have finished up.

I am not able to get the logic for doing this. Since I want to update a screen's UI which is already on stack, from a screen which is at the top of the stack.

And also, I want to keep those things at the main screen of the application whenever I start my application(just like history of the activities).

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article: 
http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/12/blackberry-threads-dynamically-update.html

It shows how to update UI from different thread using Observer Design pattern. But you can use same technique to update screen from different screens.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MVC design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Implement screens as Views which get notified when data model changed.